# React, Redux, mapStateToProps and no rerendering despite state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a strange problem with Redux and React.
The state changes properly and in `mapStateToProps` I also get the right new state but after the mapping the component will not rerender.

This way, the component doesn't rerender:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
       return (<li>{this.props.item.text}</li>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        item: state.test.byID[ownProps.itemID]
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListItem);
```

But if I split the item the components rerender:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
       return(<li>{this.props.text}</li>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        id: state.test.byID[ownProps.itemID].id,
        text: state.test.byID[ownProps.itemID].text
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListItem);
```

I have no clue why.

Reducer:

```
const startState = {
    byID: {
        'a1': {id: 'a1', text: 'test1'},
        'a2': {id: 'a2', text: 'test2'},
        'a3': {id: 'a3', text: 'test3'},
        'a4': {id: 'a4', text: 'test4'},
        'a5': {id: 'a5', text: 'test5'},
        'a6': {id: 'a6', text: 'test6'},
        'a7': {id: 'a7', text: 'test7'},
    },
    all: ['a1', 'a2','a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7']
};


export default function reducer(state = startState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TEXT':
            const newState = {...state};
            newState.byID[action.id].text = action.text;
            return newState
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are changing the `text` field in one of `byID` array's objects. With your code:

```
newState.byID[action.id].text = action.text;
```

You are mutating your state, therefore React might have problems with recognising changes since the reference of object in `item` prop does not change, only it's properties. If there is made **shallow** check, it simply won't re-render as it "suppose" object does not change at all.

In the second scenario you are returning prop `text` which is string type, so there won't be shallow check like with object, and equal comparison `===` will distinguish change and properly re-render component.

For more clarification you might want to look at [Immutability in React](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc).

The idea of maintaining immutability with spread operator:

```
const newState = {...state};
```

Is okay for top-level reference, but not for nested children objects:

> Object spread does a shallow copy of the object. Only the object itself is cloned, while nested instances are not cloned. [An easy guide to object rest/spread properties in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/)

Although mutating object seems to be the most error prone part in your provided code, the `Component` React class **can** deeply investigate object changes (`PureComponent` does not) and the problem might be related to another issue.

Comment: Tank you. I thought that the spread operate create a complete hard copy.
After changing the reduce code, everything works fine:
`const newState = {...state, byID:{...state.byID, [action.id]: {...state.byID[action.id], text: action.text}}};`

Comment: First paragraph solved my problem. Clone arrays using `slice` method, then change the cloned method and finally assign it to state. it will re-render the component.